# ¿Como hacer un login en c#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo este código en c# pero no encuntro como hacer para que el usuario se registre y se pueda logear

```
fMenu entrada;

private void btnlog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string nombre = txt_usuario.Text;
        string password = txt_contraseña.Text;


        if ((txt_usuario.Text != "") && (txt_contraseña.Text != ""))
        {


            if ((txt_usuario.Text == nombre) && (txt_contraseña.Text == password))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Bienvenido");
                entrada = new fMenu();
                entrada.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }


        }
```

Comment: A que te referis? ese codigo comprueba un usuario y password contra si mismo. que otra cosa estas buscando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pues si quieres algo simple ya casi lo consigues
agrego valores de ejemplo.

```
private void btnlog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //valores de ejemplo
        string nombre = "usuario1"
        string password = "secreto01";



        if ((txt_usuario.Text != "") && (txt_contraseña.Text != ""))
        {


            if ((txt_usuario.Text == nombre) && (txt_contraseña.Text == password))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Bienvenido");
                entrada = new fMenu();
                entrada.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }


        }
}
```

Ahora como puedes ver para extenderlo deberas guardar el valor de sesion para 
el usuario cuando se firme, los valores de usuario y pass que estan harcodeados los
deberas obtener de un repositorio digamos una base de datos o un usuario en tu archivo de configuracion.

Debes extender tu pregunta de cual es el objetivo de tu login.

saludos